# Play sound while phone is asleep

Tags: android, audio, sleep, audio-player

I am wirting a service which reminds the user in random intervalls. This service is started by an Activity and runs in the background as a service.

The challenge I am facing is, when the user puts the phone into sleep (blank screen), in some occasions the sound simply does not play. Time has run out, but the sound won't play either on time or it plays when the user wakes up the phone.

Here is some code:

```
/**
 * Starts a new thread which is checking every seconds how much time has
 * elapsed and if the point of time has come to play the sound.
 * Once the time has come, it gets the next ring time and continues
 * until it is shut down by the user
 */
private void runCheck() {
    Log.i(tag, "starting runCheck");

    Thread thread = new Thread() {
        public void run() {

            Log.i(tag, "starting LogoTimerThread");
            while (vRunningFlag) {

                try {

                    // update the notification
                    makeNotification();

                    Log.v(tag,
                            "Next Ring in : ["
                                    + helper.TimeCalculator
                                            .duration2_hh_MM_SS((vTimerNextRing - System
                                                    .currentTimeMillis()) / 1000)
                                    + " sec.]");

                    // check if time has run out
                    if (vTimerNextRing < System.currentTimeMillis()) {
                        // reset the timer
                        setNextRingTime();
                        // update the screen
                        makeNotification();
                        // play the sound
                        playLTimerSound();
                    }

                    sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
            Log.i(tag, "finished LogoTimerThread");
        }
    };

    thread.start();
}
```

The whole service is running as remote service which is set to foreground, so a notification reminds the user of the service and he can stop it that way.

Once I comment out `playLTimerSound()`, the timer would just count down. Somehow the thread gets stopped by playing of the sound.

Here is that function as well:

```
public void playLTimerSound() {
    Log.i(tag, "playLogoTimerSound - volume:" + vVolume);
    MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.enterprise);
    mp.setVolume(2.0f, 2.0f);
    mp.start();
    mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            mp.release();
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

can't aquire SCREEN_DIM_WAKE_LOCK in you scenario ?

```
@Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
     super.onCreate(icicle);




PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.SCREEN_DIM_WAKE_LOCK, "App");
wl.acquire();

}
```

Comment: Do I have to acquire the lock right before playing the sound or on create? I am not so familiar with wakelocks.